# I am always getting error "timeout expired. the timeout period elapsed prior ..... "

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, timeout, settimeout

Anyone know how to add connection timeout in this code below?
I am always getting error `"timeout expired. the timeout period elapsed prior ..... "`.

```
Private Sub FillToolStripButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FillToolStripButton.Click
    Try
        Me.SpLastTransactionTableAdapter.Fill(Me.VoyagerDataSet2.spLastTransaction, VaraccountToolStripTextBox.Text)
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to set the wait time before terminating the attempt to execute a command and generating an error.

Please note that [SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an `SqlCommand` used during `Fill` to select records from the database for placement in the DataSet, so you can use:

```
Me.SpLastTransactionTableAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 1000
Me.SpLastTransactionTableAdapter.Fill(Me.VoyagerDataSet2.spLastTransaction, VaraccountToolStripTextBox.Text)
```

Comment: Error 1 'CommandTimeout' is not a member of 'DA5ReportGenerator.VoyagerDataSet2TableAdapters.spLastTransactionTableAdapter'.   what should i do? thanks